# print a 5digit number such that if we put 1 at the beginning, the resulting 6digit number is 3x smaller than if we put the 1 @ end of the number

Tags: python

this is my code so far

```
x = 100000
while x < 100000:
y = x + 100000
z =  (3*10000)-1/(10-3)
    if y != z:
    x += 1
else: 
print(x)
```

break

I know the answer should be 42857 but it's giving me 10000

Comment: `x = 100000` means that the loop condition is immediately false and never iterates.

Comment: also `z =  (3*10000)-1/(10-3)` is constant...

Comment: How do you know the answer should be 42857? Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: No coding necessary: `3(x+100000) = 10x+1` => `299999 = 7x` => `x=42857`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop never executes because of the wrong initialization of `x`. Besides, `z` is constant (doesn't depend on `x`)

In your code it probably prints `100000` because of the broken indentation that makes `else` statement match the `while`. Since no `break` occurs, the last value of `x` is printed.

Better do a `for` loop. That works:

```
for x in range (1,100000):
    y = x + 100000
    z = x*10 + 1
    if y == z//3:
        print(x)
        break
else:
    # for loop completed without break
    print("not found")
```

or in one line, using `next` and a generator comprehension:

```
result = next(x for x in range (1,100000) if x + 100000 == (x*10 + 1)//3)
```

in both cases the result is indeed `42857`